# Reading json file and updating

Tags: java, json, gson

Im trying to understand the procedure to do what the title says.
Im doing this in java with Gson dependency.

I am getting information from another service I use, in JSON format. So I want to get that info, put some additional info in there (like date/time) and use it afterwards for searching purposes.
The procedure is :

1. Get the JSON info (lets say "id") and add it to the JSON file you have
2. Add more info to that JSON file (lets say "Date and time of upload")
3. Finally, save that updated JSON file

So I read the file:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

Do I have now to convert it to string, and then update the string, so I can finally write it back to json?

If it doesn't exist, I create an empty file and then, can I update it with Json/Gson data? or do I have to create a Json File?

```
try {
        File jsonFile = new File("C:\\uploads\\datasets");
        if (jsonFile.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println("File is created!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Excuse any newbie/stupid mistakes I've probably made, I'm trying to understand JSON. Actually, the philosophy behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation and it's nothing more than a way to format data.

Taken from [here](https://www.json.org/):

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> 1. A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
>      realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>      list, or associative array.
> 2. An ordered list of values. In most
>      languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

To address your questions:

1. Get the JSON info (lets say "id") and add it to the JSON file you have

   ```
   JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(inputFilename));
   reader.beginArray();
   reader.beginObject();

   long id = -1;

   while (reader.hasNext()) {
   String value = reader.nextName();
   if (value.equals("id")) {
     id = reader.nextLong();
   } else {
     reader.skipValue();
   }

   reader.endObject();
   reader.endArray();
   ```
2. Add more info to that JSON file (lets say "Date and time of upload")

   This will get the format in `YYYY.MM.DD-HH.MM.SS`

   ```
   String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
   ```
3. Finally, save that updated JSON file

   Create a `JsonWriter`.

   ```
   JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter(outputFilename));
   writer.beginArray();
   writer.beginObject();

   writer.name("id").value(id);
   writer.name("timestamp").value(timestamp);

   writer.endObject();
   writer.endArray();
   ```

You can read more about `JsonReader` and `JsonWriter` [here](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) and [here](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html).

Comment: That was helpful! Thanks a lot! (I can't believe I missed json.org)